# Describing my exact height

Tags: words

How do I describe my height in centimetres?

I think you can say "私は背が高いです" to say that you're tall, but how about your exact height? Would "私は背が１９０cmです" sound like broken Japanese?

I came across someone using "身長: xyz cm" when describing their height, and looking up "example sentences" in jisho.org for "身長" had a few cases of it being used for exact heights. Should it be "私は身長が１９０cmです" instead?

Comment: You can also use 背丈

Answer (score 15, accepted):

背 more literally means your spine/backbone and someone with a long, erect spine is someone who is tall, but that doesn't mean that his spine is 190cm long. (背骨 is the actual word for spine.)

身長 is literally the length of the body and is the standard way of talking about your height. So, just like you suggested, 僕は身長が190cmです.