# Different word about Back and spine

Tags: word-choice

I've seen many different words refering to back, spine like せ and せなか. So what is the right word and in which case?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8256/1628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Japanese, せなか is the usual word for "back", but it comes from the old word せ which also means "back", or "a raised portion" and which occurs in other contexts:

- [背が高い]{せがたかい} means "tall" (Here's a discussion about whether to read it せがたかい or せいがたかい: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1411676039)
- [背番号]{せばんごう} means the number on the back of a sports player

See also the entry for 背 at Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%8C