# What is 背が高い and how is it different from 高い

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I can't understand the meaning of 背が高い人. From what I've heard you can't just say 高い on a non living object, so what is the meaning of 背 exactly?

Comment: Related question: [Describing my exact height](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8256/describing-my-exact-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

高い has very wide meanings including high, tall, expensive, hot, and so on.
but usually you have to add 背 referring tall. 背 means tallness of human beings.
背が高い人 translates in verbatim "a person who is high in tallness".

Answer (score 0):

背が高い人 means "tall person".

高い人 (without 背) has a different meaning.
高い人 means "arrogant person", someone who looks down on other people.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/8517/meaning/m0u/%E5%BE%A1%E9%AB%98%E3%81%84/

Comment: 「高い人」 doesn't mean "arrogant person". We use **お**高い for "arrogant". We say **お**高くとまった人 to mean "arrogant person".